# Rails + Javascript: How do I create a button that slides/changes a form from left to right?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, button

For example, there's a form with 3 parts, A B and C. Initially the user can only see A. After filling out A and clicking a `Next` Button, the screen slides out A to the left and slides in B from the right. The user then has the option to click `Next` or `Back` to see C or A respectively. On C, the user can click Submit to submit the form, and the User is created in the database.

I'd like to have this all on a single page, without a long scrollbar at the bottom of the page if possible. If a scroll bar is necessary, a JQuery-esque one would be the preferred option.

I can't seem to find any information on something like this. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its pretty trivial to do so,

here is a working demo http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/FancySlidingForm/
here is nice tutorial http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/06/07/fancy-sliding-form-with-jquery/

Just replace the controls in this markup to what you need, and instead of buttons, you need to enable disable a **next** button

```
<div id="steps">
        <form id="formElem" name="formElem" action="" method="post">
            <fieldset class="step">
                <legend>Account</legend>
                <p>
                    <label for="username">User name</label>
                    <input id="username" name="username" />
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                    <input id="email" name="email" type="email" />
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                    <input id="password" name="password" type="password" />
                </p>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
            ...
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
```